# Spring and tag mvc resources, can't reach .css

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've the following error when I start my Spring project in my web browser in the "console":

```
GET http://localhost:8080/lbagno/$%7Bresource%7D   [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 6ms]
```

And when I see the console mode of Tomcat, I've the following message :

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/lbagno/${resource}] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

And I don't understand why.

Do you have a solution ?

Thank you

Architecture of the 'lbagno' project :

```
-- src 
   -- main
     -- java
        -- resources
           -- css
              -- normalMode
                   header.css
        -- webapp
           -- WEB-INF
             -- /pages
             -- mvc-dispatcher-serclet.xml
             -- web.xml
-- pom.xml

-- target
   -- apache-tomcat-maven-plugin
   -- classes
   -- dependency
   -- lbagno
   -- maven-archiver
   -- surefire
   -- tomcat
   -- lbagno.war
```

Structure of the lbagno.war

```
- META-INF
  - /maven
  - MANIFEST.MF
- WEB-INF
  - classes
      - com
      - css
          - normalMode
             - header.css
      - images
      - normalMode
          -css
            - header.css
      - mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
  - lib
  - pages
  - mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
  - web.xml
- index.jsp
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myblog.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

          <property value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"  name="viewClass" />

          <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
          </property>

          <property name="suffix">
               <value>.jsp</value>
          </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/src/main/resources/css/normalMode/"/>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
      org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

header.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

<head>
   <spring:url value="/resources/css/header.css" var="resource"/>
   <link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${resource}" />
</head>
```

Comment: which version of tomcat you use?

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/src/main/resources/css/normalMode/"/>
```

Location `src/main/resources` is source location! Change this line to:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="css/normalMode/"/>
```

Take look into `war` archive for proper file locations.

---

Your css files are in wrong locations too:

```
- WEB-INF
  - classes
      - com
      - css
          - normalMode
             - header.css
      - images
      - normalMode
          -css
            - header.css
```

Please put this files into `src/main/webapp`

Comment: Show us your war structure :)

Comment: You can see my war file now in the subject of the problem

Comment: move css files into webapp

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `web.xml`. Your `web.xml` should be declared as Servlet 2.4 or higher to be able to use the `JSP Expression Language` ( `${resource}` ).

Try with this `web.xml` :

```
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
          org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: I notice that my war file in the target directory hasn't been refreshed anymore since a few days ago. Do you know a maven command to update my war file ?